# Android studio device file explorer gets stuck when downloading a file

Tags: android-studio

When I try to download files from my device in Android Studios Device File Explorer the download always gets stuck.
I open the folder in the Device File Explorer, right click on the file(s) and choose "Save as...".

The problem occurs on several devices (same model).

Above the progress bar it says:

> Downloading file 12 of 14: "/data/data/com.some.name/files/data.txt" (15,9 MB / 16,8 MB)

But no matter how long I wait it doesnt continue to download.
The only hint I could find are these lines in the log file (maybe they are completly irrelevant):

```
09-06 12:49:14.385 3784-3812/? W/StorageManager: getStorageFullBytes DEFAULT_FULL_THRESHOLD_BYTES : 20971520, threadhold : 20971520
09-06 12:49:14.386 3784-3812/? W/StorageManager: getStorageLowBytes lowPercent : 5, lowBytes : 2898018304, maxLowBytes : 524288000
09-06 12:49:14.387 3784-3812/? W/DeviceStorageMonitorService: updateBroadcasts(/data) oldLevel:0, newLevel:0, seq:1
09-06 12:49:14.388 3784-3812/? W/DeviceStorageMonitorService: updateBroadcasts_filenode(/data) fn_oldLevel:0, fn_newLevel:0, seq:1
```

What could be the cause? Where could I look for anything that might give me an idea whats going wrong?

Edit:

Javi Mollá suggested it might be the file, so I tested it on a colleagues computer. It worked. So I guess its really an error related to Android studio (on my computer).

Edit2:

Uploading works.

Comment: Is it the same file?

Comment: Yes, it gets stuck at the same file, but that file is by far the biggest, so it might be a coincidence that it always gets stuck there. Also its **not** always at (15,9 MB / 16,8 MB).

Comment: Is the file ok? Maybe it's corrupted

Comment: I tested it a few times more, even with other USB cables :D. It also got stuck at other files, so its probably not the file.

Comment: Also, it works on another computer.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? Is it the same than on the other computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing this issue with 3.2 Android Studio.

Updated with 3.2.1, still, the same issue exists (Not able to download any file from **Device File Explorer** Tool).

You can try adb command for now.

```
adb pull /data/data/com.some.name/files/data.txt .
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**.

Open tab Terminal that is located at bottom in Android Studio (or cmd). Type for example:

*adb devices*
or
*adb kill-server*
etc

This will restart adb daemon and cause restart Device Explorer too.

Answer (score 1):

Faced/facing the same issue with 3.4. This is what worked for me:

```
adb exec-out run-as com.your.application.id.package cat files/data.txt > /target/folder/data.txt
```

Note that since `run-as` is used the path to the file is relative.

Answer (score 0):

It's work after Android Studio restart

Comment: yes works. I didn't expect it will work. thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

just restart Android studio and problem will be solved